# Is there a REST API for creating a payment request through Google Pay (UPI)

Tags: flutter, google-pay, paytm, rest, upi

I'm working on an event management app (using Flutter). Once I enter the guest's UPI ID/VPA, I want a request to be initiated to his account and he could pay the amount by approving it from his mobile through the concerned UPI app. Does Google Pay provide any such API? or are there any other ways this could be implemented?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/web/create-payment-method

This may be of help

Comment: I too am looking for a similar model to implement. Still looking for APIs. Please update here if you find anything more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a payment system recently in one my production applications and the easiest way is to use **Razorpay**.

RazorPay has the following payment options :

- Debit Card
- Credit Card
- UPI
- Net Banking [ includes most of the popular banks ]

I am sharing a link to the Youtube video i have used to successfully integrate it.

***Resources :***

[*Complete Razorpay intergration procedure video :*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jExrphsQlbc)

[*Razorpay Flutter plugin*](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter)

[image]